# SSRS ReportViewer Web Control - How to not show the "WaitControl" at all when rendering as Async?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I'm using the latest (2010) ReportViewer Web Control in an ASP.NET 4 project. My client wants me to suppress / hide the initial "Loading" message that gets displayed while the report is being fetched.

Yeah... I know... why hide information that tells you what's going on? But, the client wants what the client wants.

I know that if you use the report viewer control with AsyncRendering=False that you can then set the WaitControlDisplayAfter property to a ridiculously long value.

Unfortunately, I need to have AsyncRendering=True (showing multiple reports on a type of Dashboard thingy). This (according to MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer.waitcontroldisplayafter.aspx see Remarks section) will mean that the "Wait Control" will always show. (Grr-r-rr!)

So the question is, how to I *not* show this control using async rendering?

(An aside question the client asked me, was that they wanted to see a cached copy of the report while it's loading an updated one - any takers on this one?)

Thanks,
Jaans

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a way to hide the loading message by manipulating the DOM with jQuery.  Adding the following script to the page with the reportviewer did the trick:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var waitMsg = $("div[id$='AsyncWait_Wait']");
        waitMsg.wrap("<div style='display:none; visibility: hidden'></div>");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That's not only very clever, but also clean and elegant!

Answer (score 5):

Starting from Joe Camp's answer, the following works for me. I added this entry to the application's CSS file:

```
div[id$='AsyncWait_Wait']
{
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

Tested working in IE8, IE9, Chrome 21, FF10, FF15, and Safari (version 5-ish, iPad3 iOS 5.1.1).

Comment: Cool i didn't know you could use that selector in css, +1

Answer (score -1):

I will also recommend the above two codes because they are effective and esay to use.But if it didn't work out use this one.
Add the function below and call it when the pages load.

```
 private void HideLoadImage(Control ReportViewer)
{
    foreach (Control c in ReportViewer.Controls)
    {
        if ((string.Compare(c.ID, "AsyncWait") == 0))
        {        
            c.Visible = false;

            }
        if (c.HasControls())
        {
            HideLoadImage(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't recommend this. At least with ASP.NET AJAX enabled, you'll get Javascript errors when you do this.