# SSRS - remove the 'loading' popup every time report refreshes

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2016, ssrs-2014

I would like to **NOT** show the '**loading**' popup when the report refreshes because this is displayed on several monitors and it catches viewers' attention. Report is deployed to a SQL report server. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8125/is-there-any-way-to-turn-off-the-loading-message-when-a-page-refreshes-in-repo

Comment: PS - only tag the version you are using and only if it is relevant to the question.

Comment: You could cache your dataset and refresh your report from the cache... this way the report will refresh instantly and shouldn't get the loading / refreshing screen

Comment: Can I do that for a refresh that happens every few seconds? Thanks

This is what I am looking for but not sure how to implement it. Here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323694/ssrs-reportviewer-web-control-how-to-not-show-the-waitcontrol-at-all-when-re

Answer (score 1):

If you have an ASP.NET developer on hand, have them use the ReportViewer control to embed the report directly into a plain old aspx page. I've done this to a few reports, and they never show the usual "Report is being generated" message that you get when accessing them via Report Manager. (You might have to set AsyncRendering="False" on the ReportViewer control to get the desired behavior.)

This will also allow you to dress up the page a bit, and conceal the various Reporting Services toolbars, which would be ideal for a billboard display like you describe. Put a meta refresh in the page to get a 30-second refresh, and you're set.